# Ubuntu 14.04 - New User Account

Tags: password

I have a question regarding the creation of a new user on Ubuntu 14.04. When I go to "User Accounts" and click "+" to make a new account, it asks for "Account Type", "Full Name", and "Username". After selecting the account type and entering a "Full Name", it suggests a username which I accepted.

It does not ask for a password and when I try login to the new user account, no passwords are accepted. How do I set a password for this user account and why doesn't it ask this while creating the account? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a terminal

```
sudo passwd username
```

It wasn't removed. Pic is worth 1000 words.

[image]

Click where it says account disabled and you will get prompted for the password.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I still really want to know why they removed setting the password on creation :/

Comment: @Aucun edited answer to include the 2nd part of your question

Comment: I had no idea you could click that area, would be helpful if it looked like a button. Thanks for the screenshot :)

Comment: @Aucun - Agreed