# useradd not asking for a password?

Tags: 14.04, users

I created new users from the terminal using `sudo useradd -g mygroup testuser` but I wasn’t prompted to set a password? why was that? the users have now been created but I need to set a password for them, so how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/462016/ubuntu-14-04-new-user-account

Comment: Use `adduser` instead: http://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd

Answer (score 11):

It is better to create new users with `adduser` instead of `useradd`. In this way you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 9):

to set a password for the new user I ran

```
sudo passwd testuser
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the password with the root user after creating the user

`root@yourpc:~# sudo passwd username`

don't forget to run it on the root user. or you can just create your user with `adduser` that asks password itself.

For some reasons like `-gid` you might need to run the first command.

Comment: How is this different from Mo’s answer seven years ago? 

Comment: its a whole lot different, more detail it has. I encountered this and I found this answer more complete. your welcome to ignore it :))